# Вылет приложения

Tags: java, android

В каком случае возникает такая ошибка:

```
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "30.0"
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at ru.exam.inter.Updater.checkUpdates(Updater.java:78)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at ru.exam.inter.Updater.doInBackground(Updater.java:14)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at ru.exam.inter.Updater.doInBackground(Updater.java:1)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-27 18:35:02.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2665):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 11):

У Вас же в стек-трейсе все написано:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "30.0"
```

Метод `Integer.parseInt(...)` не может спарсить переданный аргумент.

Comment: И как это понять?

Comment: @turok09, Очень просто. `30.0` – это не `int`, соответственно и спарсить данное значение методом `Integer.parseInt(...)` невозможно.

Comment: Вам намекают что вы передаете float или double а не int